# Why does one accused of manslaughter need to leave the city of refuge in order to be judged?

Tags: halacha, mishna, beit-din-court

The Mishnah in Makkos 2:6 says that a person accused of manslaughter who escaped to a city of refuge needs to leave in order to be judged.

The question is: why must he leave, thereby risking his life - why can’t he just be judged inside the city of refuge?

Comment: Is there a court in that city?

Comment: It seems from the Mishna that they would be "מְבִיאִין" him as well as "מַחֲזִירִין", I assume this means by bailiffs who would also be there to ensure the justice procedures take place, which would include protecting him. Also, in direct answer to your question - doesn't he need to be judged by the court in the city that the defendants live in? See Rama Choshen Mishpat 14:1. The only way out of that might be if there is a greater court in the Ir Hamiklat, the plaintiff can try to insist on being tried there (see Tur ibid). @DoubleAA asked about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rambam [Rotzeach 5:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.5.7?lang=bi) seems to indicate that the reason the Bais Din of his city needs to get him and judge him in his own city is a gezeiras hakasuv:

> וּבֵית דִּין שֶׁל אוֹתָהּ הָעִיר שֶׁהָרַג בָּהּ שׁוֹלְחִין וּמְבִיאִין אוֹתוֹ מִשָּׁם וְדָנִין שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יט יב) "וְשָׁלְחוּ זִקְנֵי עִירוֹ וְלָקְחוּ אֹתוֹ מִשָּׁם".

> The court in the city in which the killing took place sends for the killer and brings him back to that city, as ibid.:12 states: "And the elders of his city shall send and take him from there."

The Aruch Laner [Makkos 10B](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14412&st=&pgnum=36) goes so far as to suggest that one who kills in a city that does not have a bais din is pattur but concludes that it’s only lmitzvah and not meakev:

[image]